# Django add field when the user click the button

Tags: django

Is it possible to add field in models depends on how many times the user click the button?

example: original samplemodel

```
class samplemodel(models.Model):
  username=models.CharField(max_length=500)
  category=models.CharField(max_length=500)
  date=models.DateField(max_length=500)
```

html

```
 <input type="text" name="category">
 <input type="date">
 <input type="submit">
```

if the user click the submit button twice the samplemodel will look like this

```
class samplemodel(models.Model):
  username=models.CharField(max_length=500)
  category=models.CharField(max_length=500)
  category1=models.CharField(max_length=500) /user add
  category2=models.CharField(max_length=500) /user add
  date=models.DateField(max_length=500)
  date1=models.DateField(max_length=500)/user add
  date2=models.DateField(max_length=500)/user add
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very bad idea, let's think about users clicked button 1.000 times. It means that you add 1000 fields to your model logically.You can use two ways for that.
Firstly you can add an arrayfield your model and add new Dates to this field:

```
class SampleModel(models.Model):
    # your other fields
    dates = ArrayField(
        models.DateField(),
    )
```

Other way, you can create new table contains datefield and username. You can add new record after user each clicked button.

```
 class UserClickDateModel(models.Model):
     username = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
     category = models.CharField(max_length=255)
     clicked_date = models.DateField()
```

As a suggestions, you can use foreignkey for username.Also in django camelcase used for class names generally. You can find more detail django coding style [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/)

Comment: You're welcome. Also, if you store big string inside a field you can use models.TextField() instead of models.CharField()

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you create 2 extra tables:

*CATEGORY table with a ForeignKey to USERCLICKDATEMODEL*

*DATE table with a ForeignKey to USERCLICKDATEMODEL*

That way you can have as many entries to either table as needed with a direct connection to your original table

btw. **I would not use reserved words e.g. 'DATE' for table and/or field names**